# android.support.design.widget.TabLayout - cannot resolve symbol 'design'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I tried to import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout, but I got cannot resolve symbol 'design' error.
[image]

In the First I sought that is a problem with a **implementation com.android.support:design** version (in gradle Module).
But it is not.
I managed to find the cause of this error - dependencies versions (in gradle Project).

**My dependencies version is:**

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3
```

'

So if I use older version - this is fixing the error.

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
```

I do not understand why It does not work with newest versions.
Please help me understand this, why I cannot use new versions.

**My android studio vesrion is:** 4.0

**gradle Module:**

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "mv.group.qwerty"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

buildTypes {
release {
minifyEnabled false
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
}
}
}

**gradle Project:**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: why you use `classpath` instead of usual `implementation`?

Comment: Hi Marcin, First reason: because firebase suggest to use classpath and any YouTube tutorials. Second reason: if I using  implementation instead of classpath I got next errors: (1) Gradle DSL method not found: 'implementation()'
Possible causes:
The project 'Puppy' may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0).
(2) The project 'Puppy' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
(3) The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution 1:
add this to your `build.gradle(Module:App)` dependencies,

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha3'.
```

Also Make sure that all Android Support dependencies have the same version like below:

```
dependencies {
   implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
   implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0-alpha3"
   implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
   implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha3'

}
```

Solution 2:

Did you convert your dependencies to `androidx`?
In Menu, press `Refector` and select `Migrate to AndroidX`, press `sync gradle` and it should solve this issue.
and use `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'` instead of `implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha3'`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your support. When I added 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha3'.
I got next issue, I think because I am using androidX.
Version 28 (intended for Android Pie and below) is the last version of the legacy support library, so we recommend that you migrate to AndroidX libraries when using Android Q and moving forward. The IDE can help with this: Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX... 

So I replaced my 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha08' on yours 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'.
It did not help.

Comment: so If you have user om.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha08 then instead of  android.support.design.widget.TabLayout, you need to use 
com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout

Comment: Asad khan, thanks, It is works.My mistake was that I used in gradle Module - both  two libraries: 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha08' and 'com.android.support:design'. Additionally in XSML file I used <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout/>, I didn't know that it is not a androidx. So I removed 'com.android.support:design' from the gradle, then 'android.support.design.widget.TabLayout' I changed to "com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout", then in JAVA file 'import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout' I changed to 'import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout'.

Comment: Happy coding :-)